# Restore SQL Server database from bak file to different partition (Permission Denied)

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, permissions, database-restore

On Ubuntu 17.04, I have a .bak file in `/var/opt/mssql/backup/` that I am trying to restore to a separate partition because the partition I have SQL Server installed on does not have enough room for the database to be restored to.

I am getting an error like the following: `The operating system returned the error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on '/media/<my-user-name>/<some-folder>/<mdf-file>.mdf'.`

I've tried to use `chmod` and `chown` to change the permissions of that folder on the second partition, but I'm not getting it quite right because I still get the error.

- What user is trying to write to that folder in the second partition?
- How do I get that user account permissions to successfully restore the database to that folder?

I had this second hard drive connected via a caddy and was able to perform this task no problem.  But as soon as I installed the ssd internally, Ubuntu has not allowed whatever user account I'm using in the SQL Server CLI for it this time.

Thanks!

### Update

I changed the owner of the second partition/ssd to `mssql` and now I have permission to restore the database to this location.  I would assume that if the owner of that whole ssd is mssql, I might have other permission issues down the road using this ssd for other things.  Is there a way to configure this so that my personal user account as well as `mssql` has permissions to this folder enough to own it?  I don't think two different accounts can own a folder, but is there a way to permit multiple accounts with sufficient access to perform these actions?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I ran across several of these already and the problem is that they are all using Windows and SQL server management studio. I'm on Ubuntu and thus need to find a command line way of doing this as far as I know

Comment: So someone is actually using Sql Server on Linux. Who woulda known? :D

Answer (score 0):

I won't pretend to be knowledgeable about this, but I had a permissions issue while trying to restore a .bak that was on a network vm to my local device, it worked when I added it to a .zip with 7-share, then copied it to the location I wanted and extracted it.

I had the permissions issue when I tried to move it without zipping, and as far as I remember I still had this issue when I used send to compressed (zipped) folder. I'm not sure why, maybe someone else can elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by deleting the old database, creating a new one and restoring the backup to the new one.

My problem was probably cause by the fact that I had created the database in evalutation edition of MS SQL Server and I wanted to rewrite it by backup in new instalation of developer edition.